# NodeJS base64 image encoding not quite working

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, microsoft-graph-api, adaptive-cards

I am using [API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/profilephoto_get) to get user's profile photo from O365 cloud. Based on the doc it says response contains 
*The binary data of the requested photo. *

I would like to use this image to be displayed by Data URI format. Ex:-

"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA
ANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU
5ErkJggg=="

where everything after data:image/png;base64,.... is image data in Base64.

I unable to get Base64 encoding working for the image data I am getting from API. Not sure if I am consuming raw binary img data correctly and converting it correctly to Base64.

To verify: 
I upload my URI data here to online editor & it never parses my data/image. Instead if I upload an image [here](http://www.dailycoding.com/Utils/Converter/ImageToBase64.aspx) & to get Base64 data then upload URI in 1st editor it does display correctly. So I am guessing by Base64 conversation isn't correct.

**CODE in nodejs:-**

```
let base64ImgTry1 = Buffer.from('binary-data-from-api').toString('base64')

//OR

var base64ImgTry2 = new Buffer('binary-data-from-api','binary').toString('base64');

let imgURI_1 = 'data:image/png;base64,' +base64ImgTry1
let imgURI_2 = 'data:image/png;base64,' +base64ImgTry1
```

none of these imgURI_1 , imgURI_2 works. Not sure if I am going wrong consuming binary-data-from-api.

I also tried this NPM library https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-data-uri

in which i used this method -> encode(data, mediaType) where data was direct response from API.

https://www.site24x7.com/tools/datauri-to-image.html

Comment: So are you getting the image correctly?

Comment: I'd be interested to see how you get and "handle" this so called `'binary-data-from-api'`

Comment: I just make http get using node's request to get img binary-data. Getting img correctly as I verified API call in Postman

```
request.get({
            url: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user123@microsoft.com/photo/$value`,
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'image/jpg',
                authorization: 'Bearer '+token
            }
        },
            function (err, response, body) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('>>> Application error: ' + err);
                } else {
//  let binary-data-from-api = body
}
```

Comment: @Bravo any thoughts please ?

Comment: yes, I think more than about 1 line of code in a comment is impossible to read

Comment: So let me reiterate it in words.

I using this API ---> https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/profilephoto_get

and making http get cal with nodejs request module. 

documentation says response Contains the binary data of the requested photo. The HTTP response code is 200.

Comment: I followed this tutorial  [Encoding and Decoding Base64 ](https://stackabuse.com/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-node-js/)

with example for nodejs fs module but it errors saying it needs string as input. But what I have as api response if image bytes.